# Kubernetes: Container not able to ping www.google.com

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes

I have `kubernetes` cluster running on 4 `Raspberry-pi` devices, out of which 1 is acting as `master` and other 3 are working as `worker` i.e `w1`, `w2`, `w3`. I have started a daemon set deployment, so each worker is running a pod of 2 containers.

`w2` is running pod of 2 container. If I `exec` into any container and ping `www.google.com` from the container, I get the response. But if I do the same on `w1` and `w3` it says `temporary failure in name resolution`. All the pods in kube-system are running. I am using `weave` for networking. Below are all the pods for kube-system

```
NAME                                READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
etcd-master-pi                      1/1       Running   1          23h
kube-apiserver-master-pi            1/1       Running   1          23h
kube-controller-manager-master-pi   1/1       Running   1          23h
kube-dns-7b6ff86f69-97vtl           3/3       Running   3          23h
kube-proxy-2tmgw                    1/1       Running   0          14m
kube-proxy-9xfx9                    1/1       Running   2          22h
kube-proxy-nfgwg                    1/1       Running   1          23h
kube-proxy-xbdxl                    1/1       Running   3          23h
kube-scheduler-master-pi            1/1       Running   1          23h
weave-net-7sh5n                     2/2       Running   1          14m
weave-net-c7x8p                     2/2       Running   3          23h
weave-net-mz4c4                     2/2       Running   6          22h
weave-net-qtgmw                     2/2       Running   10         23h
```

If I am starting the containers using the normal docker container command but not from the kubernetes deployment then I do not see this issue. I think this is because of `kube-dns`. How can I debug this issue.?

Answer (score 4):

You can start by checking if the dns is working

Run the nslookup on kubernetes.default from inside the pod, check if it is working.

```
[root@metrics-master-2 /]# nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.96.0.1
```

Check the local dns configuration inside the pods:

```
[root@metrics-master-2 /]# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local ec2.internal
options ndots:5
```

At last, check the kube-dns container logs while you run the ping command, It will give you the possible reasons why the name is not resolving.

```
kubectl logs kube-dns-86f4d74b45-7c4ng -c kubedns -n kube-system
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When you say running the nslookup from inside the pod, do you mean from inside the container or on the master device. Thanks

Comment: You can do it inside the container also. It is the same thing.

Comment: What does default in kubernetes.default means. Does this default means default namespace so which means I will have to mention my namespace while nslookup

Comment: Also I do not see any activity in logs of kube-dns while I run ping command

Comment: kubernetes.default resolves to the kubedns service which has clusterIP of 10.96.0.1 in my case. That was just to check if kubedns is working fine. If it works fine, it means the problem is somewhere else. I just deployed kubernetes cluster of 3 node(1 master, 2 worker) with the weave CNI. On my cluster everything is working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination Prafull. I did run the nslookup command and got this response `Server:  192.168.0.21
Address: 192.168.0.21#53

** server can't find kubernetes.default: NXDOMAIN`

Comment: I run the nslookup command in master. In your case it displays the Name and the Address of kubernetes.default but in my case it says it can't find. What can be the reason.? Thanks

Comment: You are showing a NXDOMAIN reply, which means it did get a reply from some DNS server, and that server declared it had never heard of "kubernetes.default".
I suggest looking in the logs of kube-dns to see (a) it is actually that server which is replying and (b) why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183692/discussion-between-prafull-ladha-and-s-andrew).

Answer (score 0):

This might not be applicable to your scenario, but I wanted to document the solution I found. My issues ended up being related to a flannel network overlay setup on our master nodes.

```
# kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-qwer                 1/1     Running   0          4h54m
coredns-asdf                 1/1     Running   0          4h54m
etcd-h1                      1/1     Running   0          4h53m
etcd-h2                      1/1     Running   0          4h48m
etcd-h3                      1/1     Running   0          4h48m
kube-apiserver-h1            1/1     Running   0          4h53m
kube-apiserver-h2            1/1     Running   0          4h48m
kube-apiserver-h3            1/1     Running   0          4h48m
kube-controller-manager-h1   1/1     Running   2          4h53m
kube-controller-manager-h2   1/1     Running   0          4h48m
kube-controller-manager-h3   1/1     Running   0          4h48m
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-asdf   1/1     Running   0          4h48m
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-qwer   1/1     Running   1          4h48m
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-zxcv   1/1     Running   0          3h51m
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-wert   1/1     Running   0          4h54m
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-sdfg   1/1     Running   1          4h41m
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-xcvb   1/1     Running   1          4h42m
kube-proxy-qwer              1/1     Running   0          4h42m
kube-proxy-asdf              1/1     Running   0          4h54m
kube-proxy-zxcv              1/1     Running   0          4h48m
kube-proxy-wert              1/1     Running   0          4h41m
kube-proxy-sdfg              1/1     Running   0          4h48m
kube-proxy-xcvb              1/1     Running   0          4h42m
kube-scheduler-h1            1/1     Running   1          4h53m
kube-scheduler-h2            1/1     Running   1          4h48m
kube-scheduler-h3            1/1     Running   0          4h48m
tiller-deploy-asdf           1/1     Running   0          4h28m
```

If I exec'd into any container and ping'd google.com from the container, I get a bad address response.

```
# ping google.com
ping: bad address 'google.com'

# ip route
default via 10.168.3.1 dev eth0
10.168.3.0/24 dev eth0 scope link  src 10.168.3.22
10.244.0.0/16 via 10.168.3.1 dev eth0
```

> ip route varies from `ip route` run from the master node.

altering my pods deployment configuration to include the `hostNetwork: true` allowed me to ping outside my container.

my newly running pod ip route

```
# ip route
default via 172.25.10.1 dev ens192  metric 100
10.168.0.0/24 via 10.168.0.0 dev flannel.1 onlink
10.168.1.0/24 via 10.168.1.0 dev flannel.1 onlink
10.168.2.0/24 via 10.168.2.0 dev flannel.1 onlink
10.168.3.0/24 dev cni0 scope link  src 10.168.3.1
10.168.4.0/24 via 10.168.4.0 dev flannel.1 onlink
10.168.5.0/24 via 10.168.5.0 dev flannel.1 onlink
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 scope link  src 172.17.0.1
172.25.10.0/23 dev ens192 scope link  src 172.25.11.35  metric 100
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 scope link  src 192.168.122.1

# ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.6.110): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.6.110: seq=0 ttl=55 time=3.488 ms
```

## Update 1

My associate and I found a number of different websites which advise against setting `hostNetwork: true`. We then found [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40761) and are currently investigating it as a possible solution, sans `hostNetwork: true`.

> Usually you'd do this with the '--ip-masq' flag to flannel which is 'false' by default and is defined as "setup IP masquerade rule for traffic destined outside of overlay network". Which sounds like what you want.

## Update 2

It turns out that our flannel network overlay was misconfigured. We needed to ensure that our configmap for flannel had net-conf\.json.network matching our  networking.podSubnet (`kubeadm config view`). Changing these networks to match alleviated our networking woes. We were then able to remove `hostNetwork: true` from our deployments.